# Congratulations Yannis Rizos and Thomas Owens: Our Newest Community Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators

Congrats to Yannis Rizos and Thomas Owens! They are our newest members to the P.SE Moderator Team. I have a feeling this site is only going to get better.

Comment: Yes congratulations to you both! I was hoping the two of you would win.

Comment: Congratulations, 2 excellent choices.  I knew our community was smart. :)

Comment: Congrats! I don't envy your new positions, but sure do support and respect them.  This will be good.

Comment: Congrats Thomas & Yannis!

Comment: Congrats thomas & Yannis!

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: Strong, strong field of candidates, but I feel that was the right result. Congrats guys. Apologies to everyone else. Next time.

Answer (score 18):

For those interested in election results:

```
OpenSTV version 1.7 (http://www.OpenSTV.org/)

Suggested donation for using OpenSTV for an election is $50.  Please go to 
http://www.OpenSTV.org/donate to donate via PayPal, Google Checkout, or
Amazon Payments.  

Certified election reports are also available.  Please go to 
http://www.openstv.org/certified-reports for more information.

Loading ballots from file programmers-stackexchange-com-2012-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 9 candidates and 298 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 298 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Programmers Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
9 candidates running for 2 seats.

 R|Thomas Owens|maple_shaft |Yannis Rizos|World Engine|Jae         |Jonathan Kho
  |            |            |            |er          |            |o           
  |------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
  |SnOrfus     |Karl Bielefe|Glenn Nelson|Exhausted   |Surplus     |Threshold   
  |            |ldt         |            |            |            |            
================================================================================
 1|   80.000000|   34.000000|   69.000000|   13.000000|    8.000000|   20.000000
  |   31.000000|   22.000000|   21.000000|    0.000000|    0.000000|   99.333334
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices.
================================================================================
 2|   81.000000|   34.000000|   69.000000|   14.000000|            |   22.000000
  |   31.000000|   23.000000|   23.000000|    1.000000|    0.000000|   99.000001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Jae and transferring votes. All losing candidates
  | are eliminated.
================================================================================
 3|   83.000000|   36.000000|   74.000000|            |            |   26.000000
  |   31.000000|   23.000000|   23.000000|    2.000000|    0.000000|   98.666667
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating World Engineer and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
================================================================================
 4|   86.000000|   37.000000|   76.000000|            |            |   28.000000
  |   32.000000|   33.000000|            |    6.000000|    0.000000|   97.333334
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Glenn Nelson and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidates Karl Bielefeldt and Glenn Nelson were
  | tied when choosing candidates to eliminate. Candidate Glenn Nelson was
  | chosen by breaking the tie at round 1.
================================================================================
 5|   93.000000|   40.000000|   80.000000|            |            |            
  |   38.000000|   37.000000|            |   10.000000|    0.000000|   96.000001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Jonathan Khoo and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
================================================================================
 6|   95.000000|   47.000000|   90.000000|            |            |            
  |   44.000000|            |            |   22.000000|    2.999999|   92.000001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Karl Bielefeldt and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidate Thomas Owens has reached the threshold
  | and is elected.
================================================================================
 7|  112.000000|   53.000000|   98.000000|            |            |            
  |            |            |            |   35.000000|   34.666666|   87.666667
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating SnOrfus and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated. Candidate Yannis Rizos has reached the threshold
  | and is elected.

Winners are Thomas Owens and Yannis Rizos.
```

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't have lost to a better group of people. Congratulations guys!

Answer (score 7):

I called it but I didn't expect that big a margin; well done.